# Javascript SetInterval / addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, setinterval, addeventlistener

I just started learning Javascript, and I am trying out various functions.
This is my HTML page used to try the function setInterval():

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wait!</title>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoader', () =>{
            setInterval(count, 1000);
        });

        let counter = 0;

        function count(){
            counter++;
            document.querySelector('#counter').innerHTML=String(counter);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><span id="counter">0</span> seconds have passed...</h1>
    <h3>Cherish your time...</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

It should be able to display an HTML page that has an h1 saying  seconds has passed, increasing  by 1 every 1000 milliseconds, i.e. 1 second.

The setInterval function should run the count() function once every 1 second, which changes the
variable `counter` and displays the current value on `#counter`.

When I run this program, however, nothing seems to happen. Only a webpage saying 0 seconds.
When I go to the console (Google Chrome), there are no errors occurring, and when I query the `counter` value by typing `counter`, it stays at 0.
Also, when I type `counter = 4`, the text on the webpage does not change. Therefore, I think the
problem is at `document.addEventListener()`, although I don't know what it is.
I would be very thankful if you can answer this problem.

Comment: Do note that, like most languages, delays in form of `setIntervals` isn't executing exactly after the set time (1000 ms in this case), but not _until_ this time have passed. Especially for javascript, that can't run multiple threads and needs to wait until other stuff is done in the "queue", this is important to keep in mind. Possibly above what you need to learn for now, but I always go with `requestAnimationFrame` with timers.

Comment: thanks!         ‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Answer (score 0):

Oh, snap! Got it. The problem was I misspelt `'DOMContentLoaded'` as `'DOMContentLoader'`.